# CSV Dynamic Unique Columns

Tags: powershell, csv, variables, dynamic, unique

I need to import a number of CSV files, dynamically create variable names based on header row values, assign column values to column arrays, and unique column values to unique column arrays.

```
ID;PlayGolf;Day;Temperature;Outlook;Humidity;Windy;
1;no;05-Jul;hot;sunny;high;FALSE;
2;no;06-Jul;hot;sunny;high;TRUE;
3;yes;07-Jul;hot;overcast;high;FALSE;
4;yes;09-Jul;cool;rain;normal;FALSE;
5;yes;10-Jul;cool;overcast;normal;TRUE;
6;no;12-Jul;mild;sunny;high;FALSE;
7;yes;14-Jul;cool;sunny;normal;FALSE;
8;yes;15-Jul;mild;rain;normal;FALSE;
9;yes;20-Jul;mild;sunny;normal;TRUE;
10;yes;21-Jul;mild;overcast;high;TRUE;
11;yes;22-Jul;hot;overcast;normal;FALSE;
```

For example, in the above CSV file, I would create `$ID`, `$PlayGolf`, and so on. The array `$PlayGolf` would contain the values `@("no", "no", "yes", "yes",..."yes")` and array `$PlayGolfUnique` would contain the values `@("no", "yes")`.

The following snippet outlines how far I have got towards a solution:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, HelpMessage = "Input data: (e.g. Input.csv")]
    [string]$inputFile = "Input.csv",
    [Parameter(Position = 2, HelpMessage = "Data delimiter: (e.g. ;")]
    [string]$dataDelimiter = ";"
)

$main = {
    Begin {
        Write-Host "SO Question Begin..." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
    }
    Process {
        try {
            $line = (Get-Content $inputFile -TotalCount 2)[0]
            $delimiterCount = ([char[]]$line -eq $dataDelimiter).Count

            $colHeaders = @(((Get-Content $inputFile)[0..($delimiterCount - 1)] -split ($dataDelimiter))[0..($delimiterCount - 1)])
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception)" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
            Break
        }
    }
    End {
        if ($?) {
            Write-Host "Completed Successfully." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
            Write-Host "SO Question End..." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Green
        }
    }
}

& $main
```

Comment: Hmm ... why don't you use standard Powershell cmdlets? Something like this:  `Import-Csv -Path C:\sample\csv.csv -Delimiter ';' -OutVariable CSV` `$Csv.playgolf | Select-Object -Unique -OutVariable PlayGolfUnique`

Comment: @Olaf, I need a generic solution that will handle CSV files without knowing the number of columns or header names.

Comment: You might have mentioned that in your question.  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf. Apologies. I incorrectly assumed mentioning that I needed to "import a number of CSV files" would communicate that requirement.

Comment: Some of us are not native english speakers. It might be helpful to be as clear and correct as possible. Anyway, Ansgar pointed you already in the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to re-invent the wheel. Import the CSV, select the values of the column in question into one variable, then get the unique values from that variable and assign it to another variable.

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -Delimiter ';'

$PlayGolf       = $csv | Select-Object -Expand 'PlayGolf'
$PlayGolfUnique = $PlayGolf | Select-Object -Unique
```

If you want to do that for all columns without knowing the number of columns and/or header names I'd recommend using a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-3.0) instead of individual variables:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -Delimiter ';'

$ht = @{}
$csv[0].PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $col = $_.Name
    $ht[$col] = $csv | Select-Object -Expand $col
    $ht["${col}_Unique"] = $csv | Select-Object -Expand $col -Unique
}
```